# Is there a way to limit the prediction-classes for a Keras model

Tags: python, keras, prediction

I have created a simple Keras neural network that is trained on **two** datasets (with 2 sets of classes combined(one of 19 classes and one with 54 classes) and I would like to limit the predictions of the model to only one set of classes (i.e. only the classes from the test data set (the 54 classes)).

This is my (relevant) code:

```
network = Sequential([])
network.add(Dense(units, activation='relu', input_shape=(768*3,)))
network.add(Dropout(dropout))
network.add(Dense(len(rels), activation='softmax'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
network.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

trainX, valX, trainy, valy = train_test_split(trainX, trainy, random_state=2020, test_size=0.1)
    
history = network.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(valX, valy), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_no, verbose=0)

y_pred = network.predict(testX, verbose=0)
```

I would like y_pred, instead of having a probability for all 73 classes, to have a standard probability of 0 for the first 19 classes and the predicted probability for all the other classes.

I would like to be able to get the test accuracy and test loss for this modified model.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: that makes no sense to me, seems like this problem should be addressed outside of keras